# Can one write an assertion on `self` with `patch.object`?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

Say I patch a member function of a class with [unittest.mock.patch.object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object)

Can one write an assertion on another member variable of the object via `self` at the time of the mock's call?

Consider the following example

```
from unittest.mock import patch


class ToBeTestedClass:
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        self.a = a

    def to_be_tested_function(val: int) -> None:
        # self.a is important here
        return


def intermediary_function_expected() -> None:
    t = ToBeTestedClass(3)
    t.to_be_tested_function(10)


def test_main():

    with patch.object(
        ToBeTestedClass, "to_be_tested_function"
    ) as mock_to_be_tested_function:
        intermediary_function_expected()

        # TODO
        # Check that when to_be_tested_function was called the t.a was 3.
```

Inside the test, I would like to check whether the object's `a` member variable had the value of 3 at the time of the call to the mocked function.

---

There are other ways to achieve the same thing. I could mock the object itself, even use monkeypatch…. I am specifically wondering about this `patch.object` approach.

---

Looking at the call args of the mock after `intermediary_function_expected` function call looks like this

```
(Pdb) p mock_to_be_tested_function.call_args
call(10)
```

So the `self` is not available at the call args, even though `t.to_be_tested_function(10)` is equivalent to `ToBeTestedClass.to_be_tested_function(t, 10)` . At least this is in python 3.10.8

Comment: You are patching the class instead of the object - if you use `patch.object`, you have to pass an existing instance as argument, so this won't work.